# How to get request body of SearchClient.SearchAsync request in application insights telemetry initializer?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-cognitive-search, azure-sdk-.net

I am going to migrate our service to use Azure.Search.Documents SDK instead of raw HttpClient GET/POST to query documents from azure search.

My current code logs the azure search request body to application insights dependencies log in telemetry initializer as this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize application insights.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="telemetry">Telemetry to be initialized.</param>
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (telemetry is DependencyTelemetry)
        {
            var dependencyTelemetry = telemetry as DependencyTelemetry;

            if (dependencyTelemetry.TryGetOperationDetail("HttpRequest", out var request))
            {
                var httpRequest = request as HttpRequestMessage;

                var body = httpRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                dependencyTelemetry.Properties["Body"] = body;
            }
        }
```

}

But this code does not work anymore if we use SDK SearchClient.Search(), the request from dependencyTelemetry.TryGetOperationDetail is null. My guess is, the SearchClient.Search() also use HttpClient POST to send request to azure search, don't know why cannot get request with same code.

We would like make logging code change as minimum as possible. What is the suggested approach to log body of SDK request with minimum code?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the different [logging options](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/core/Azure.Core/samples/Diagnostics.md#logging) available when working with the Azure SDK, including ways to [enable logging the content](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/core/Azure.Core/samples/Diagnostics.md#enabling-content-logging).

Comment: Thanks Mohit. I tried enabled logging content, but still cannot find the body from either request or dependencies table.

Comment: Could you open an issue in our GitHub repo (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net) and paste the snippet of code where you are trying to enable logging content.